# Android studio in ubuntu os not showing my Real device

Tags: android

Android Studio  doesn't show my `Xolo A500s` for run android application.
In choose device option my mobile not detected.

Comment: With `adb devices` can you see your device?

Comment: No. Not See ,my os is Upantu

Answer (score 1):

You should provide more information about your problem, we do not know what you already tried.

In the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) you have the information that you need to use a real device when testing. A very basic step that you might not have done is to enable USB Debugging:

> Enable USB debugging on your device.
>
> On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option
>   under Settings > Applications > Development. On Android 4.0 and newer,
>   it's in Settings > Developer options.
>
> Note: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by
>   default. To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap
>   Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find
>   Developer options.